# Remove this Yellow Color from Gestures

Tags: android

```
mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.spells); 

if (!mLibrary.load()) 
{ 
     finish(); 
} 

GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures); 
gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this); gestures.getGestureColor();
```

How to Remove this Yellow Color from Gestures...

I  don't  any color when i drag one start position to end. please help me for android code

Comment: Where is **`Yellow`** Color !!!

Comment: When i drag than draw one Yellow color line

Comment: where i past this code..

Comment: In, the question it self dear, see how other people are asking the question with their code.

Comment: mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.spells);
        if (!mLibrary.load()) {
         finish();
        }

        GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
        gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
        gestures.getGestureColor();

Comment: not here in comment, add it in the question, are you getting me ?

Comment: i have not repution so i ask que??  after 20 minite

Comment: you don't require  20 rep to ask a question, 20 rep is for chatting in the room.

Comment: which answer ? your question's answer or how to ask the question's answer ?

Comment: ya i got my question answer..

Comment: then delete the question, as if it is not useful for future visitor, i think

Comment: how to delete i m new in stack overflow

Comment: there is a delete link, below your question ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line in your XML

```
android:gestureColor="#000000"
```

This code `#000000` representes the black color in hexadecimal

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. There are two methods for your instance of your GestureOverlayView. 
They are called setGestureColor() and setUncertainGestureColor()
 (gestureOverlayView.setGestureColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);            gestureOverlayView.setUncertainGestureColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);)

Please find the whole example below. It is a snippet from my onCreate-method of my Main Activity. The second and third lines solved your problem.

```
ActivityGestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView = new GestureOverlayView(this);
        gestureOverlayView.setGestureColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        gestureOverlayView.setUncertainGestureColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        gestureOverlayView.addView(inflate);
        gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener((OnGesturePerformedListener) this);
        MainActivity.gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
        if (!MainActivity.gestureLib.load()) {
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(gestureOverlayView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem and I finally found the solution. If you look at the source code for GestureOverlayView, you'll notice a boolean test for mHandleGestureActions at line 559 (and others) that makes a call to [private void] setCurrentColor when drawing the gesture. Unfortunately mHandleGestureActions is only set when you use the OnGesturePerformedListener listener.

This is a total hack; but it works:

Create a stub view that implements the OnGesturePerformedListener and add that to your overlay's list of OnGesturePerformedListeners. You don't have to
do anything with the listener; but it needs to be a separate view from the one you're using as the REAL listener (or you'll crash your app). Then add your
OnGesturingListener or OnGestureListener view that does the REAL work.

Comment: Can you post some source code of the suggestion that you made?  It might help the original user accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(new OnGesturePerformedListener() {

        public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {


        }
    });
    gestureOverlayView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view XML file add this in GestureOverlayView.

```
android:gestureColor="#0000ff"
android:uncertainGestureColor="#0000ff"
```

It is too late to answer it but may be it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code inside xml

```
android:gestureColor="@android:color/transparent"
```